# Kinect - Size of a skeleton capture file

Tags: kinect

I have to make some calculations concerning the size of a skeleton capture file without having an actual Kinect device...
So I came to the conclusion that for a 15 minutes skeletal tracking, the file size would approximately be 8Mbytes. Is this right ?

Comment: Skeleton data is just an object of `Joint` coordinates.  The size of the file depends on the file format, how often you save the data, the number of points you save, and a large number of other factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just answer my own question.

If you only save the skeleton view, you are only saving the joints coordinates and their orientation. It doesnt take much space, and should be about the file size I mentioned in the question.